# Can I improve this code using delegates?

Tags: c#, beginner, wpf

I guess I might use delegates. But I'm not certain if I can apply for it.

Sorry if the code is a mess.  I'm a beginner and am still learning.  For that reason, I need a little of help to improve this code. It's not finished.

I'm creating a Math quiz system. And there are many questions as you will be able to see in it, they're so different and I have a difficult moment to create the classes.

```
    private int[] Generate_Fraction(int li1, int ls1, int li2, int ls2)
    {
        int numerator = randomizer.Next(li1, ls1);
        int denominator = randomizer.Next(li2, ls2);

        int[] fraction = new int[2];
        fraction[0] = numerator;
        fraction[1] = denominator;

        return fraction;
    }

    // Decimals
    private double[] GeneratePattern5(double[][] limits)
    {
        double[] decimals = new double[limits.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < limits.Length; i++)
        {
            bool flag;
            double decTemp;

            do
            {
                flag = false;
                decTemp = GetDoubleBetween(limits[i][0], limits[i][1], (int)limits[i][2]);

                if (Exists(decimals, decTemp, i))
                {
                    flag = true;
                }

            } while (flag);

            decimals[i] = decTemp;
        }

        return decimals;

    }

    // Fractions like: 6/60
    private int[][] GeneratePattern7(int[][] arrayLimits)
    {
        int[][] fractions = new int[arrayLimits.Length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayLimits.Length; i++)
        {
            bool flag;
            int[] fracTemp = new int[2];
            do
            {
                flag = false;
                fracTemp = Generate_Fraction(arrayLimits[i][0], arrayLimits[i][1], arrayLimits[i][2], arrayLimits[i][3]);
                fracTemp[1] *= fracTemp[0];

                if (Exists(fractions, fracTemp, i))
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            } while (flag);

            fractions[i] = fracTemp;
        }

        return fractions;
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean generics, not delegates?

Comment: Can you be more specific, which part of the code do you think is verbose?

Comment: The return types and methods of generating the values differ greatly, so I don't see any obvious way to do it.  What do you think is wrong with the way you have it?

Comment: Well, that's an example code from my solution. I've got to generate many patterns, if you see the subroutines GeneratePattern5 and GeneratePattern7, they're doing the same thing, only verify if the data exists in the list.

Do you get me?

Comment: Well, 7 is a lucky number.  How the number of toes on your foot figures into this is pretty unguessable.

Comment: Oscar, if you post your patterns functions again and ask how to use generics and delegates to make a single function from the two, I will post an answer with code.

Comment: There's a lot of issues with your code. Don't use arrays to hold different data. Create a type for that or use a [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx). What does `GetDoubleBetween()` and `Exists()` methods do? What are the arguments for? You don't provide those implementations and the arguments themselves tells us nothing about what they _could_ be (made worse by the use of arrays). We can make some guesses but they'll only be guesses, you should make it very clear what they are and what they do.

Comment: Anyway, I uploaded the code below. I know that there's a lot of issue Jeff. Do you think I should use that data structure?

Please read the lastest post.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you can move the Exists inside the condition and remove the flag variable. This will change the loop to...

```
        double decTemp;

        do
        {
            decTemp = GetDoubleBetween(limits[i][0], limits[i][1], (int)limits[i][2]);
        } while (Exists(decimals, decTemp, i));
```

I believe that this is more semantically in line with what you are trying to accomplish.  You could do the same thing inside the GeneratePattern7 method as well.  Doing so will reduce a lot of clutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplication from this code. There are a couple of ways to do this but as a result you'll get really complicated code. I think you should leave it as it is now. There are situations when it's better to have some duplication than to have complicated code.